# How to cast objects to double with minimum casting

Tags: c#, casting

Let suppose i have 5 objects and each object contains double values.

I want to sum them up so that

```
double result=obj 1+obj 2+obj 3+obj 4+obj 5;
```

One way is to cast each object to double  and then sum them up.

```
double result=(double)obj 1+(double)obj 2+(double)obj 3+(double)obj 4+(double)obj 5; //let suppose this cast works!
```

Is there any shorter way to do this?

Comment: I don't think so, well they are `double` and is good only when added in that sense

Comment: Can't you just have the objects detect that they're being added together (or to a double) and then return a double?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put them into an array and use some LINQ onto it:

```
double sum = new[] { obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4 }.Cast<double>().Sum();
```

However, the best way would be keeping the doubles as doubles and don't put them into objects.

Comment: I got them from  data table as objects.

Comment: You could use a typed DataSet or use the DataRow.Field<T> extension method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394.aspx

Comment: You have to import System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll, too.

Answer (score 3):

Cast, but with style...:

```
static double SumDoubleObjects(params Object[] objs)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        foreach (object curr in objs)
        {
            sum += (double)curr;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Possible upgrades:

1. You could use extension method
2. Add type safe checking

HTH